# need help javascript array = [] and how to output name of variable in array with value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question about array as below

```
array = {}
```

and

```
array = [];
```

its same or not?.

also wish to ask

```
array { ID1 : "apple", ID2 : "Orange"}
```

and

```
array [ID1 : "apple", ID2 : "Orange"];
```

which is correct?.

now i coding my code with below and need your help to teach me about ARRAY.

```
var Store = [ store = 0, store1 = 0, store2 = 0,store3 = 0,store4 = 0];
var stock1 = 77,stock2 = 47,stock3 = 37,stock4 = 27,stock5 = 17;

for(i=0;i<stock1;i++){
store[0]++
}
var Sum_1 = Store;
document.getElementById('show1').innerHTML=Sum_1;
```

output will be

```
77
```

my question is how to i output it become

```
store = 77
store1 = 47
store2 = 37
```

Most with ID or Name together and value.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Just start reading: [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 1):

`[]` are used for a literal **Array** declaration, `{}` for a literal **Object** declaration.

Arrays are initialized without a value by using:

```
var my_array = [];
```

and with values:

```
var my_array = [1, 2, 3];
```

Note that you **cannot** set the index by this. You would have to do:

```
var my_array = [];
my_array["one"] = 1;
// etc.
```

You can then get "1" back by `my_array["one"]`

If you want to get the actual index name or "*key*" then you will need to do some trickery:

```
var outputString = "";

function ListAll()
{
    for(var key in my_array)
    {
        if(my_array.hasOwnProperty(key)) // Check if the key is actually a property (index)
        {
            outputString += key + " = " + my_array[key]; // add to string
        }
    }

    alert(outputString); // or assign the string to a div, whatever you need
}
```

in this example, `key` would be the index and `my_array[key]` the actual value

Comment: Mean i can't output my array with Name or ID together with value in that ID or Name?.

Comment: I just gave you a function that does exactly that. ID = index = key

Comment: So sorry, can you please write me a simple array which can diplay Name or Id after collect value from other.

Comment: Make this easy to read, i have try your code and found very usefull,
however its still something wrong.

It output with 0 = value, 1 = value.
can it back to the name of array = [store , store1]
store = value , store1 = value

can this be done??